# What does face-width mean?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, topological-graph-theory

What is the meaning of the term **face-width**? I have seen the term used as a property of an embedding of a graph on a surface. I haven't found a definition.

Comment: http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~mohar/Book/Ch5.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](http://www.sfu.ca/~mohar/820_2006/Week9.pdf), [here](http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~mohar/Reprints/1997/BM97_DM176_Mohar_ApexGraphs.pdf), and [here](http://compgeom.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/comptop/notes/shortest-noncontractible.pdf) for the definitions of face-width.

Comment: A noncontactible closed curve is a closed curve that cannot be contracted to a point, right?

Comment: @becko Yes. *This is a filler*